# Error in solving equations with scipy.optimize.fsolve

Tags: python, equation, factorial

I'm a newbie in python and I'm trying to implement fsolve to retrieve a variable from a function.

The function (fidelity in the code) is the following:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2jQV.png)

I want to retrieve N, given n and eta, for a P value of 0.5

This is the code I wrote:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
np.set_printoptions(suppress=False)
# defining the factorial of a number
def factorial(n):
    f = 1.
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        f = i * f
    return f

eta = 0.9

n = 2

N0 = 4

#defining fidelity
def Pnn(N, eta, n):
    P = factorial(N) * eta**n / ( factorial(N-n) * N**n)
    return P

def func_opt(N, eta, n):
    Pn = Pnn(N, eta, n)
    return Pn - 0.5

res = fsolve(func_opt, N0, args=(eta, n), xtol=0.001)


print(res)
```

When I run it, the following errors appear:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in fsolve(func, x0, args, fprime, full_output, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    158                'diag': diag}
    159 
--> 160     res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
    161     if full_output:
    162         x = res['x']

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, eps, factor, diag, **unknown_options)
    224     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    225         args = (args,)
--> 226     shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
    227     if epsfcn is None:
    228         epsfcn = finfo(dtype).eps

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     22 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     23                 output_shape=None):
---> 24     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     25     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     26         if (output_shape[0] != 1):
```

With the conclusing statement:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

If anyone can explain me what I am doing wrong, it would be really appreciate it!!

Comment: Why does that function need to be optimised?

Comment: @DSteman I want to find the value of N to obtain P(n|n) = 0.5 (given eta and n)

Comment: What does the formula represent? Isn't that some probability formula for a certain distribution?

Comment: P is the probability to detect n photons (upon sending n ones), with N detector each one with an efficiency eta